# Date comparison rule going in Infinite loop

Tags: date, comparison, drools

I am trying to execute a set of 5 rules listed below-

Let's say there are two entities- Entity1 and Entity 2. 
Entity1 contains 3 date type variables - Date1, Date2, Date3
Entity2 contains a date type variables - Date4

1. Rule 1 - If Date1 > Date2, then throw an Error Message
2. Rule 2 - If Date2 > Date3, then throw an Error Message
3. Rule 3 - If Date3 < Date4, then throw an Error Message
4. Rule 4 - If Date1 > Today's Date, then throw an Error Message
5. Rule 4 - If Date3 < Today's Date, then throw an Error Message

After a while, I noticed that the logs are growing and the system goes out of memory.

Digging in a bit more I enabled TRACE on org.drools package and found that the rules are going in a loop and not getting stopped.

I am using Drools Workbench 7.2.0 Final

Please suggest how to proceed with this.

**Edit** -
Added snip of the DRL file [DRL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym2eJ.png)

Comment: You have something in these rules that makes them fire in a loop. You'll have to remove the cause.

Comment: I don't see any cyclic loop getting formed in between these rules. Let me know in case you want me to share the DRL files for these rules.

Comment: Please share your DRL and the way you are interacting with the session.

Comment: How could anyone guess what goes wrong without seeing the code?

Comment: We are using Stateless Kie session and Rest calls to execute these rules. I have also attached a snip of the DRL for all 5 rules

Comment: Don't put code in images, and don't link important information.  You can paste all that code after right-shifting by 4 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as one `modify( $passport )` is executed, all rules with matching LHS are liable to be re-fired. no-loop blocks only the rule where the modify was done; it does not inhibit a loop going over two or more rules.

The best technique to inhibit this kind of loop is to add in all rules a constraint that detects when the modify has been done, e.g.

```
Passport( response == null, ... )
```